# Optimal way to avoid a recursion for tree walking

Tags: javascript, recursion

so I am fairly new to javascript and I was trying to write a special shift scheduling code for a friend. The way it currently works is as follow :

```
function walk(currentDay) {
    var today = allWorkDays[currentDay]; // An array of all workdays we need to schedule
    var vertices = fetchCombinationsForToday(today); // Fetch an array of 0 length or more
                                                // containing possibilities for the day
                                                // according to rules set by user
    for (var i=0; i<vertices.length; i++) {
         [we add the vertices[i] to a running array]
         walk(currentDay+1);
    }
    if (currentDay == sumOfAllDays) { // We are at a leaf
           analyzeSchedule(); // This will keep a copy of the current schedule 
                              // if it has a higher score than X
    }
    [some business to pop the last node/day we added to our global array]
}
```

Now the rules specified in the comments are rules that usually analyze the last 5-10 last added elements(days) and return what could be the shifts for today.

The problem I have here is that I want the program to be able to come up with schedules even with an array of more than a thousand days, but I would exceed the function calls limit due to recursion. Is there any way to walk a tree without using recursion in javascript? I can't seem to find one even though most say that problems solvable by recursion can be solved by loops and vice versa.

Keep in mind that the vertices array is big (20-30 elements) early in the tree but quickly gets small (0-5 elements). I never ran this code [EDIT: and got a "function calls limit reached" error] by the way it is all theory [EDIT: the fact that I will reach it] for now.

Comment: run your code, debug it, rewrite your code, do a structure for it and think about it. you seriously have to run your code. pseudo code is good but won't get you to your solution and we will not provide the solution for you

Comment: @EvilP i concur, and I would also add this sounds like a pristine time to use some TDD; you know the all the ins and outs, and you want to verify behavior. Pick your js unit testing framework of choice, and start coding. If you run into a more specific implentation problem, then might be ask *that* question.

Comment: Sorry, but the pseudo-code isn't enough of a description of what you're trying to do for me (and perhaps others) to understand the problem well enough to suggest alternatives.

Comment: So all in all, get your things together and develop some code. You will see it makes fun and you will come over things you wouldn't have thougt of ! And by the end off the day you can be proud on yourself to have achieved it on your own, without help !

Comment: I am basically asking if there is an obvious way to do tree walking without recursion since I know next to nothing about the subject (or computer science theory in general). Just so I don't go "Oh I should have asked before putting in X hours of effort for nothing knowing there is a limit to deep recursive calls". Oh and by "never ran" I mean't I never ran the code to the limit of the call stack, it is just that I know I will have to go further than this limit. I am thankful that you spent time to read my problem though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScript Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) provide methods to push/pop and shift/unshift values onto/off of their beginning and end, so you can use them like a queue.  For example:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2];
a.push(3); // => 3
a; // [0, 1, 2, 3]
a.shift(); // => 0
a; // [1, 2, 3]
a.pop(); // => 3
a; // [1, 2]
```

This way you can walk a tree structure and keep track of nodes to-be-visited by pushing and popping/unshifting from an array.

Comment: Thank you so instead of using closure to keep track of the different vertices I would use an array (of arrays). i.e. VerticesAtLevel[0] = [x, y, z] where x,y,z are possible vertices, and as long as the amount of vertices > 0, I can keep a counter of which level in the tree I am at, and keep an array of the current path I am on. So currentPath.push(VerticesAtLevel[currentLevel][0]) then VerticesAtLevel[currentLevel].shift(); followed by currentLevel++; I guess I never thought of keeping track myself of the vertices, since I was already tracking the path...